# Enable eth0 by default on Fedora 12

Tags: linux, networking, fedora, fedora-12, networkmanager

On Fedora 12 eth0 is disconnected (by the NetworkManager) by default until I manually enable it from GNOME. I need to make it connected even if I start my box in runlevel 3 or 4. How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit file /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 and be sure there is line like this:
`ONBOOT = yes`